# Why my pages come in English even the current language is another?

Tags: plugin, language

Until wednesday, everything was fine but for two days it is so strange. 
I am using DirectPHP plug-in to create my own pages. And use template's language files for the constant expressions and labels in the page.

I use the language file in this way:

```
$titles = array('', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_TITLE_1', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_TITLE_2', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_TITLE_3', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_TITLE_4');
$expressions = array('', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_EXPRESS_1', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_EXPRESS_2', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_EXPRESS_3', 'TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_EXPRESS_4');
```

I double checked that

1. if corresponding label exists in both language files
2. if there is any typographic error (even if so, I could see key's itself instead of corresponding value)

I also have copied my template for each language. Nothing changed.

I see labels and comments in English in both Turkish and English pages.
What could be the problem? I have not made any update, any change.

Comment: What Joomla version are you using? Have you updated Joomla recently? Have you enabled Language debugging in the Joomla backend to see if any error are being thrown in the frontend?

Comment: No, none of them i did. İ use joomla 3.3.6

Comment: In which case, enable language debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found athe error!

I discovered that two lines were side by side accidentally.

```
...
TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_TITLE_1 = "Title 1"TPL_MY_TEMPLATE_TITLE_2 = "Title 2"
...
```

After hitting enter key the problem has gone. I must confess that I have seen the problem using language debugging. I did not know language debugging until Lodder suggested. Thanks.